# SQL: How to make participation constraint in a table

Tags: sql, create-table, erd

Let's say, bank schema is as follows:

```
Employee = {*ID*,salary}
Branch = {*BranchNum*, Location}
```

If the relation has both participation constraint and key constraint:

```
Employee ==> workAt -- Branch  //every employee must work at one branch
```

I can force a participation constraint, by setting **BranchNum** as **NOT NULL**:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    ID           INTEGER,
    BranchNum    INTEGER     NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES Employee
    FOREIGN KEY (BranchNum) REFERENCES Branch
)
```

**However,** If there is Only participation constraint but No key constraint:

```
Employee === workAt -- Branch  //every employee must work at one or some branches
```

How do I put participation constraint when creating a table?

Answer (score 1):

If you want:

> //every employee must work at one or some branches

Then you have a 1-n relationship.  You would implement this with a junction table:

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeBranches (
    EmployeeBranchId INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    EmployeeID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    BranchNum INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeId)
    FOREIGN KEY (BranchNum) REFERENCES Branch(BranchNum)
);
```

Comment: `EmployeeBranchId` is unnecessary. A unique key is required on `(EmployeeID, BranchNum)`. You're also not handling the requirement that an employee must work at at least one branch, which requires an additional FK constraint from `Employee.EmployeeId` to `EmployeeBranches.EmployeeId`. Doing this isn't popular since it requires transactions with deferred constraint checking to populate, but the OP should know it can be enforced if required.

Comment: @reaanb . . . It may be a matter of style, but I like having a single unique primary key in all tables.  That is especially true for this table, because I might expect another table to be referring to rows -- say a table that had the hours an employee is scheduled at the branch or when s/he worked there.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what you are referring to are surrogate keys and while they are used, if you care about referential integrity, you won't create surrogate keys as they can induce violations of 3rd normal form.